# Passing GET Parameters via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following code that captures my 'Team_ID' Get parameters and I'm trying to post it to a form on another page via Jquery. I'm using a script that posts a form to another page and I need all of the variables and data that is already in place. Just trying to see how I can pass my 'var teamid' along with form that posts:
*post("formpage.php?val=1&"+$("#formid").serialize(),*

```
$('#CreateEvent').click(function(){

var $_GET = {};

document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
function decode(s) {
return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
}

$_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});

var teamid = ($_GET["team_id"]);

 {
$.post("formpage.php?val=1&"+$("#formid").serialize(), {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it as another querystring parameter.

```
$.post("formpage.php?val=1&"+$("#formid").serialize() + "&teamid=" + teamid, {

});
```